# Using a two button mouse, how do I add a driver to any axis?

Tags: drivers, axis

With a normal mouse you can easily access another panel when right clicking the specific axis as wished but I am unable to do this because I am using an i-mac provided mouse which despite emulating the 3 button mouse i have been unable to find the right keys to do this action.
How would I do this?

[[image: Transforming the rotation and Etc.1]